# Trading view- How to use an indicator from two different charts

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

TradingView. Pinescript.

I'm looking for a way to use an indicator from two different charts
For example, i'd like to get Net Value of ETHUSDT and divide it with the Net Value of BTCUSDT

So the combined indicator will calculate: NV ETHUSDT / NV BTCUSDT

I wasn't able to find how to get data from 2 different sources
Also, NV of ETHBTC doesn't give the results i am expecting